# Change the size of a sub-figure?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

How can I make the scatter plot take up, say, 75% of the horizontal and vertical space?

```
using CairoMakie

    n = 3000
    r = randn(2,3000)
    x = @view r[1,:]
    y = @view r[2,:]
    
    fig = Figure(resolution = (1200, 800), font = "sans", fontsize = 20)
    ax1 = (Axis(fig[1, 1]))
    density!(ax1, y; bins = 20, color = :orange, strokewidth = 1,
        strokecolor = :black, label = "20 bins")
    
    ax3 = Axis(fig[2, 1]; xlabel = "value", ylabel = "counts")
    ax4 = Axis(fig[2, 2]; xlabel = "value", ylabel = "counts")
    scatter!(ax3, x, y; markersize = 4, color = :black,label="samples")
    axislegend(ax3; position = :rt)
    
    density!(ax4, x; label = "default",direction=:y)
    fig
```

Which currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change them after the fact with

```
rowsize!(fig.layout, 2, Auto(3))
colsize!(fig.layout, 1, Auto(3))
```

See https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/tutorials/layout-tutorial/ for more info on building layouts.
[image]

Also, as Mikael writes in the comment below, you should probably link the axes with

```
linkxaxes!(ax1, ax3)
linkyaxes!(ax3, ax4)
```

when aligning the plots like this.

Comment: I would emphasize the use of `linkyaxes!` and `linkxaxes!` which is seems important here as well!